# Custom javascript file is not refreshed

Tags: javascript, cache

I embedded a JavaScript file inside a custom extension via the buildForm hook. The file gets loaded and does its job, however it is not reloaded reliably after an update. When I upload a new version of the file it takes quite some time until it is picked up by CiviCRM, sometimes hours. I have cleared caches and disabled asset caching, didn't help.
I am on Drupal 9 and CiviCRM 5.67.0. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... a JavaScript file ... When I upload a new version of the file it takes quite some time until it is picked up by CiviCRM, sometimes hours. I have cleared caches and disabled asset caching, didn't help. ... `composer civicrm:publish` doesn't seem to help with this... I am a total newbie in CiviCRM development and don't understand the caching going on here.

Yeah, there are many layers of caching in real-world systems. Even experienced folks will lose track of them.

**Short thought**: Check the references to your JS file. There should be a "resource caching code" (*random suffix*).

**Long explanation**:  These symptoms sound like an issue in the browser-based caching and URL-construction. I don't have a reference to your codebase, so I'll make up an example.

Many HTTP servers enable caching for static files, such as `jquery.min.js`. It works like so:

```
<!-- The HTML page requires `jquery.min.js` -->
<script
  type="text/javascript" 
  src="/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

```
<!-- So the browser requests the file -->
GET /sites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

```
<!-- Then the server sends the file along with caching instructions -->
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 96830
Cache-Control: max-age=7200

!function(a,b){"object"==typeof...
```

The server tells the browser to cache `jquery.min.js` for 7200 seconds (2 hours) -- which is great for performance but frustrating for deployment. For a clean deployment, one needs a work-around.

In CiviCRM, the *conventional work-around* is to append a random suffix to the URL. For example, I went to [this demo page](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/info?id=3&reset=1) and used "View Source" to find `jquery.min.js`. The actual URL has a suffix `?s3tkpz`.

```
<!-- Here's how the HTML actually references the file -->
<script
  type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm
                 /bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?s3tkpz">
</script>
```

```
<!-- So the browser requests the file -->
GET /sites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?s3tkpz
```

When CiviCRM has a major change on the server-side, it will switch out the suffix.

**`jquery.min.js?s3tkpz` => `jquery.min.js?neWc0d3`**

This doesn't actually *clear* the browser caches -- but as far as the browser is concerned, it looks like a different URL for a different file. The old caches become irrelevant. The browser will re-read the file.

This convention is *extremely common* for CiviCRM code. Several methods - like `addScriptFile()` and `addStyleFile()` from [Resources API](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/) - will add the code by default. (It's so common that we take for granted...) But it's not absolute or universal. You might need to do one of these:

- Switch to `Civi::resources()->addScriptFile()` or `Civi::resources()->addStyleFile()`
- Use `Civi::resources()->getUrl()` and set the third option (`$addCacheCode=TRUE`).
- Lookup the cache-code (`Civi::settings()->get('resCacheCode')`) and manually append it to a URL.
- Tell your browser to force-reload (usu `Ctrl-Shift-R` or `Cmd-Shift-R`).

(*I don't know if the above is actually your problem - but it does fit the symptoms: you're working with static JS files and clearing server-side caches and not seeing the expected content. Also, the behavior of HTTP caches can vary between different web-servers - e.g. your local dev server and production web server might have different caching policies.*)

(*Also note that the random suffix may look a bit different depending on the environment and code-flow. It might look like `?xxxxxx` or `?r=xxxxxx`, but it's the same concept either way.*)

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer! My solution was easier, but you pointed me in the right direction. I basically had to purge and configure our proxy cache. Your explanation gave me some extra learnings though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Following-up on Coleman's comment about `composer civicrm:publish`.... I don't know if that was confirmed to be part of the issue here. But here's a little braindump about when that should or shouldn't be necessary.

**Assumptions**: You have a typical Civi-D9/D10 layout (as per `civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin`). You are deploying custom/contrib extensions.

**Considerations**: The location and mechanism of the download can vary, depending on your local-configuration/preferences/etc.

- **Location**: Where is the extension code stored? Typically, it's either the public folder (`sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/`) or the private folder (`vendor/`).
- **Mechanism**: Which mechanism performs the download? Typically it's either the built-in downloader (`CRM_Extension_Downloader`) or a manual downloader (`git clone` or `wget && unzip`) or a `composer`-based downloader

**Expectations**: There are two typical approaches.

1. For extensions in the public folder `sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/`...

   - It makes sense to me to use the built-in downloader and/or manual downloader.
   - The assets (JS/CSS/PNG/etc) are already public. These downloaders do not integrate with `civicrm-asset-plugin`. (It would be complex+unnecessary.)
   - You shouldn't have to call `composer civicrm:publish`... because it's fundamentally not needed.
2. For extensions in the private folder (`vendor/XXX/YYY/`)...

   - It makes sense to me to use `composer` as the downloader.
   - The assets (JS/CSS/PNG/etc) are private and need to be copied to a public location. This is why `civicrm-asset-plugin` integrates into `composer` - so that it can automatically publish these assets.
   - You shouldn't have to call `composer civicrm:publish` in typical usage... because `civicrm-asset-plugin` hooks into other `composer` commands. It should run automatically (during `composer install` or `composer require` or `composer update`).
3. For other arrangements... that's getting into oddball territory. I might see cases where you need to manually call `composer civicrm:publish`. But we really need to clarify the scenario. Here are some examples of oddball scenarios:

   - Manually editing files in `vendor/`
   - Configuring `extensionsDir` to point at a private folder
   - Using `composer` to download extensions into a public folder

(There may be mitigations to make the oddball scenarios better. For example, if you frequently do direct edits in the `vendor/` tree, then you should configure [`CIVICRM_COMPOSER_ASSET=symdir` or `file-mode: symdir`](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/civicrm-asset-plugin#options).)

Comment: I am uploading the javascript file with scp into the `sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/<myext>` directory and as you have said `composer civicrm:publish` doesn't seem to help with this. I am a total newbie in CiviCRM development and don't understand the caching going on here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run the command `composer civicrm:publish`. See [note in the upgrade guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal8/#clear-cached-files) (which really ought to be more prominent)!

Comment: This command doesn't seem to help with an extension in `sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/` does it?